# Should I use global const vector or function that returns this vector every time it get called

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new in c++ and I'm making a dummy quiz game and i perplexed to save the questions bank whether in

```
const QVector<QString> AllQuestions = QVector<QString>() << "question 1" << "question 2";
```

or

```
static QVector<QString> AllQuestions() {
   return QVector<QString>() << "question 1" << "question 2";
}
```

Which is better in terms of performance.
Note the bank will not be used much

Comment: Why do you care about performance here? Have you profiled your code and found it to have a bottleneck?

Comment: it might take more memory space? it would be a negligible amount though.

Comment: the bank is very big it's almost 20mb of string lines

Comment: would you run `AllQuestions()` only once?

Comment: No, 6 or 7 times

Comment: but `AllQuestions` is only initialized once, right?

Comment: Yes, AllQuestions() will have the vector hand coded on it and won't be changed

Comment: The variable, right? Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: Yes, the const var AllQuestions  will be initialized once, it will be global var

Comment: I think a variable would be better since the same data isn't being allocated every time the function is run. I'm likely wrong though as I haven't tested it. I'm only saying a weak theory I have.

Comment: go for a third approach: inside the static method define the static vector and return it. It is as fast as the first approach and safer.

Comment: So you make a 20MB Q/A bank in code? Such banks - are mostly kept in text files (mabe json/xml) then red once into a data structure.

Comment: I think he's doing that, or else it would make the code very hard to read @marcinj

Comment: I ran a test using 1000000 random numbers, and I couldn't find much of any difference. I only ran the variation of `AllQuestions()` once though.

Comment: ok, So the answer is there is no difference?

Comment: I'm answering right now, sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 1):

As @Axium has mentioned in the comments, the performance difference will be negligible. The only difference is that the first approach does not create a local variable each time for returning, so it will be more performant (even a few mili-seconds).

But what I do not like about the first approach is that if in future you define another global/static variable that is dependent to `AllQuestions`, you will be in trouble because you cannot define an order of initialization for global/static variables. Because of that, what I propose is to use something like this:

```
static QVector<QString> AllQuestions() {
   static QVector<QString> all_questions = { "question 1", "question 2"};
   return all_questions;
}
```

Comment: Each time AllQuestions are called a whole collection is being copied. If that is 20MB then thats bad idea. Make it at least return a reference. Also how would you implement initalization of this collection if questions should be read from file?

Answer (score 1):

If its 20MB size, then you should make sure you will keep a one copy of it in memory. So if you need to return it from some function then return it by const reference ie. :

```
const QVector<QString>& foo() { return myBank; }
^^^^^ ~~~ !           ^ ~~~ !
```

Usually you would create a class which will initialize your myBank collection and provide accessors to it:

```
class MyBank {
  QVector<QString> myBank;
   public:

  MyBank(const QString& questionBankPath) {
      // here read myBank from file once, or create it somehow also once
  }

  // Gets bank for read only purposes (efficent way)
  const QVector<QString>& getBank() { return myBank; }
};
```

According to [Why do Qt's container classes not allow movable, non-copyable element types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584665/why-do-qts-container-classes-not-allow-movable-non-copyable-element-types) `QVector` does not support move semantics, which makes it inefficent in certain code uses.

Comment: Never return a pointer/reference of an internal state of an object. It is not a good practice.

Comment: @Gupta I agree, a getter function could be better ie. : `const QString& getString(int n) const { .... }`, but it depends on API requirements. The point was to present how to keep a single instance in memory. Its worth adding that `MyBank` class instance should be either kept in some Application like global object to make sure its not copied, or in singleton object.

Comment: In addition, you are using two step initialization in the code (using int() ) that is not recommended as well. If you have a global object of MyBank, who should call Init()?

Comment: @Gupta I am not sure if I understand - you mean Init() should be private and called in MyBank constructor? This is implementation dependend, suppose MyBank instance is kept as a variable in some Application class instance. And When its constructor is called - some required data is not yet initialized. This is when Init is usefull.

Comment: ¨People would say it is a design issue if you can construct a not yet ready object and requires a `Init` function.

Comment: Ok, to not promote bad design, I changed Init to constructor.

Comment: @marcinj at least in this case, you can avoid it.

Comment: Making a class just to hold a value seems like overkill. I'm happier with @Gupta's solution.

Comment: Singleton is considered an anti-pattern, I also wouldnt recomend it for keeping a collection. Code is always being changed, new features are being added - this is why clases, abstractions etc. were invented.

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR - If you don't want memory spikes when running the function, just use something similar to this: `vector<int> bruh = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,... };`. If that doesn't matter, then you can use either.

### Detailed description on how I came to this conclusion:

I ran a new test using a `vector` containing 1,000,000 random numbers (I didn't use more as it started to take a lot of time). First, I created this function and ran it 7 times (I ran it on the same variable):

```
vector <int> test()
{
    vector<int> bruh;
    for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        bruh.push_back(rand());
        //std::cout << bruh[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return bruh;
}
```

After running this, I noticed that there were memory spikes when it was ran, but then it went down (this isn't using pointers though, which would likely keep the used memory at the same level) as seen in this screenshot from VS.

[image]

However, when I ran code similar to the first bit of code given, there was no memory spikes as expected. [image]

Therefore, if you want to the minimal amount of memory used **at all times**, then you're better off using your first code. However, it doesn't really matter in the long run in my opinion.

Comment: Firstly, `QVector` is different from `vector`. `int` is also trivially copyable, while `QString` probably isn't. Thus, I don't think this test reflects OP's use case. Could you include the calling code as well? There could be some RVO or moving going on.

Comment: @iz_  RVO? Could you specify?

Comment: Good experimental data.

Comment: The `vector` probably isn't being copied when it is returned due to RVO. Your calling code is probably calling the same function in a row, hence the memory spikes of something being destroyed then constructed again.

Comment: I tried using pointers and a vector so they wouldn't have been garbage collected, but  I got the same thing. My full code is here: https://pastebin.com/qRAMUNbU

I didn't use `reverse` as I believe it won't have any difference on my new code.

Comment: @Axium: To provide code link, you might use some online IDE link as ideone coliru, godbolt ([Demo](https://ideone.com/wrgMSv).) Your provided code is wrong as it return address of local variable: you have dangling pointer then.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn’t think about that since VS usually takes them away most of the time. I’ll fix it right now. @Jarod42

Comment: Sorry, just checking back on this question because I'm interested in the performance aspects of this question. What exactly do you mean by "garbage collected"? Could you post your updated code?